# Conforming approximations in FEM

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

I often read in finite element text books that we seek a conforming approximation (say) for $X_0^h \subset H^1_0$, where $H^1_0$ is a Sobolev space and $X_0^h$ is a finite dimensional approximation. Then they go on to introduce the finite elements which are conforming. However, I've not read anywhere which tells me:

1. Why is it necessary to have a conforming approximation space
2. What exactly is a confirming space (in simple terms, without heavy functional analysis)
3. What implications this has on the approximation (in terms of convergence/error estimates)

This is a typical example from a text book:

> For a given partition of $\Omega$, a conforming approximation of $H^1 (\Omega)$ is a space of continuous functions defined by a finite number of parameters (degrees of freedom). This is usually achieved by using a space of piecewise polynomial functions on the elements K of the partition for $\Omega$. The degrees of freedom are then a set of linear forms on the set of polynomials on K.

Then they begin to introduce the finite element basis functions.
From that I can just about figure out what a conforming approximation is, nothing more.

Can someone tell me more about this? - or point me in the right direction.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not necessary to have a conforming method, but it simplifies the numerical analysis (e.g., error estimates). A popular non-conforming method is the [Discontinuous Galerkin method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_Galerkin_method).
2. A function space $X_0^h$ is conforming iff $X_0^h \subset H_0^1$. If you know that functions in $X_0^h$ are polynomials on the cells of your mesh, you have $X_0^h \subset H_0^1$ iff all your functions are continuous, i.e., you have no jumps between different cells.
3. I am not really sure, what you would like to ask. With non-conforming methods, you can have the same approximation quality as with conforming methods, but the proofs differ. For conforming methods, you typically use [Céa's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9a's_lemma) + interpolation error estimates, for non-conforming methods you need the Lemma of Strang + interpolation error estimates.